# Need explanation SELECT query on many to many relationship

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables related through another (many-to-many)

This is a schema excerpt:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    user_id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    email    TEXT    NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE alias (
    alias_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    address  TEXT    NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE alias_member (
    alias_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    user_id  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(alias_id, user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(alias_id) REFERENCES alias(alias_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id)  REFERENCES user(user_id)   ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I have this query that satisfies my needs:

```
SELECT email
FROM
    user,
    alias,
    alias_member
WHERE 
    user.user_id = alias_member.user_id
    AND alias.alias_id = alias_member.alias_id
    AND alias.address = 'foo@domain.tld';
```

A friend suggested me another query that works too but I don't get it:

```
SELECT
    email
FROM
    user
INNER JOIN
    (alias INNER JOIN alias_member ON alias.alias_id = alias_member.alias_id) ON user.user_id = alias_member.user_id
WHERE address='foo@domain.tld';
```

Would anyone explain it for me?

Comment: What database system you are using this with?

Comment: I'm using this with SQLite3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your version uses a *very* old `JOIN` syntax from the ANSI-89 standards - as in 1989. In 1992, the standard was updated to adopt the `JOIN...ON` syntax. You can read about the differences and their adoption in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334201/why-isnt-sql-ansi-92-standard-better-adopted-over-ansi-89).

The problem with listing tables in a `FROM` and then listing the conditions in the `WHERE` is that it's very easy to forget a condition somewhere. How easy would it be to accidentally write:

```
SELECT email
FROM
    user,
    alias,
    alias_member
WHERE 
    user.user_id = alias_member.user_id
    AND alias.address = 'foo@domain.tld';
```

Now, your friend's version also uses a weird convention (the "nested" `JOIN`). Here, it's trying to help with the fact that you have `alias_member` as the last table in the `JOIN`, but is needed to connect the other 2 tables. If `alias_member` is the first table, the syntax gets a bit cleaner:

```
SELECT
    email
FROM
    alias_member 
INNER JOIN
    user
  ON alias_member.user_id = user.user_id
INNER JOIN
    alias 
  ON alias_member.alias_id = alias.alias_id
WHERE address='foo@domain.tld';
```

Comment: Selected this answer based on the fact that now the query is clearer to me. @RDFozz made an excellent explanation too.

Answer (score 2):

It's not actually another query - it's a rewriting of the existing query, to make it more explicit what's happening.

Your original `FROM` clause, with a list of three tables separated by commas, is actually an implicit `INNER JOIN` of the three tables, with the criteria for the `JOIN` specified in the `WHERE` clause. It's generally considered better coding to make your `JOIN`s explicit, and to include the criteria for the `JOIN`s in the ON clause of the join. This makes it easier to understand how the tables are meant to fit together.

The one criteria that's not specific to a `JOIN` is left in the `WHERE` clause. This isn't limiting data based on how the various tables are related, but based on matching a field in one table regardless of the relationship.